# Encountering 'tuple index out of range' error when running Torchaudio with SpecAugment- need help to resolve

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, torchaudio

## Encountering IndexError: tuple index out of range when using SpecAugment - need help to resolve this issue.

When I tried to run the code from [biyoml/End-to-End-Mandarin-ASR: End-to-end speech recognition on AISHELL dataset (github.com)](https://github.com/biyoml/End-to-End-Mandarin-ASR), I encountered a "tuple index out of range" error, and I personally seem unable to resolve it (due to my limited experience in this area). I really hope someone can help me with this issue.

The error message is as follows:

```
TRAIN set size: 120098
DEV set size: 14326
---
Epoch: 1
Learning rate: 0.000300
Training:   0%|                                                                                                          | 0/1877 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 166, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 132, in main
    for (xs, xlens, ys) in train_tqdm:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1178, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 681, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 721, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/gemini/code/ASR/data.py", line 42, in __getitem__
    x = self.specaugment(x)
  File "/gemini/code/ASR/data.py", line 77, in specaugment
    x = torchaudio.transforms.TimeMasking(Tclamp)(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchaudio/transforms/_transforms.py", line 1176, in forward
    return F.mask_along_axis(specgram, self.mask_param, mask_value, self.axis, p=self.p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchaudio/functional/functional.py", line 863, in mask_along_axis
    mask_param = _get_mask_param(mask_param, p, specgram.shape[axis])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

**The contents of the `data.py` file are as follows:**

```py
""" Load and preprocess data.
"""
import torch
import torchaudio
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.utils.rnn as rnn_utils
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


class ASR(Dataset):
    """
    Stores a Pandas DataFrame in __init__, and reads and preprocesses examples in __getitem__.
    """
    def __init__(self, split, augmentation):
        """
        Args:
            augmentation (bool): Apply SpecAugment to training data or not.
        """
        self.df = pd.read_csv('%s.csv' % split.upper())
        self.tokenizer = torch.load('tokenizer.pth')
        self.augmentation = (augmentation and (split.upper() == 'TRAIN'))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """
        Returns:
            x (torch.FloatTensor, [seq_length, dim_features]): The FBANK features.
            y (torch.LongTensor, [n_tokens]): The label sequence.
        """
        x, y = self.df.iloc[idx]
        x, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(x)
        # Compute filter bank features
        x = torchaudio.compliance.kaldi.fbank(x, num_mel_bins=80, sample_frequency=sample_rate)   # [n_windows, 80]
        # CMVN
        x = self.cmvn(x)
        # SpecAugment
        if self.augmentation:
            x = self.specaugment(x)
        # Stack every 3 frames and down-sample frame rate by 3, following https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01769.
        x = x[:(x.shape[0]//3)*3].view(-1,3*80)   # [n_windows, 80] --> [n_windows//3, 240]
        # Tokenization
        y = self.tokenizer.encode(y)
        return x, y

    def cmvn(self, x):
        """
        Cepstral mean and variance normalization.
        """
        mean = torch.mean(x, dim=0)   # [80]
        x = x - mean                  # [n_windows, 80]
        std = torch.std(x, dim=0)     # [80]
        x = x / (std + 1e-10)         # [n_windows, 80]
        return x

    def specaugment(self, x, F=15, mF=2, T=70, p=0.2, mT=2):
        # TODO: Allow user to tune these parameters in config file.
        """
        SpecAugment (https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08779). We discard the time warping policy for simplicity.

        Args:
            x (torch.FloatTensor, [seq_length, dim_features]): The FBANK features.
            F, mF, T, p, mT: The parameters referred in SpecAugment paper.
        """
        x = x.T   # [n_windows, 80] --> [80, n_windows]

        # Freq. masking
        for _ in range(mF):
            x = torchaudio.transforms.FrequencyMasking(F)(x)

        # Time masking
        Tclamp = min(T, int(p * x.shape[1]))
        for _ in range(mT):
            x = torchaudio.transforms.TimeMasking(Tclamp)(x)
        return x.T

    def generateBatch(self, batch):
        """
        Generate a mini-batch of data. For DataLoader's 'collate_fn'.

        Args:
            batch (list(tuple)): A mini-batch of (FBANK features, label sequences) pairs.

        Returns:
            xs (torch.FloatTensor, [batch_size, (padded) seq_length, dim_features]): A mini-batch of FBANK features.
            xlens (torch.LongTensor, [batch_size]): Sequence lengths before padding.
            ys (torch.LongTensor, [batch_size, (padded) n_tokens]): A mini-batch of label sequences.
        """
        xs, ys = zip(*batch)
        xlens = torch.tensor([x.shape[0] for x in xs])
        xs = rnn_utils.pad_sequence(xs, batch_first=True)   # [batch_size, (padded) seq_length, dim_features]
        ys = rnn_utils.pad_sequence(ys, batch_first=True)   # [batch_size, (padded) n_tokens]
        return xs, xlens, ys


def load(split, batch_size, workers=0, augmentation=False):
    """
    Args:
        split (string): Which of the subset of data to take. One of 'train', 'dev' or 'test'.
        batch_size (integer): Batch size.
        workers (integer): How many subprocesses to use for data loading.
        augmentation (bool): Apply SpecAugment to training data or not.

    Returns:
        loader (DataLoader): A DataLoader can generate batches of (FBANK features, FBANK lengths, label sequence).
    """
    assert split in ['train', 'dev', 'test']

    dataset = ASR(split, augmentation)
    print ("%s set size:"%split.upper(), len(dataset))
    loader = DataLoader(dataset,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        collate_fn=dataset.generateBatch,
                        shuffle=True,
                        num_workers=workers,
                        pin_memory=True)
    return loader


def inspect_data():
    """
    Test the functionality of input pipeline and visualize a few samples.
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    BATCH_SIZE = 64
    SPLIT = 'train'

    loader = load(SPLIT, BATCH_SIZE)
    tokenizer = torch.load('tokenizer.pth')
    print ("Vocabulary size:", len(tokenizer.vocab))
    print (tokenizer.vocab)

    xs, xlens, ys = next(iter(loader))
    print (xs.shape, ys.shape)
    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        print (ys[i])
        print (tokenizer.decode(ys[i]))
        plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(xs[i].T)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inspect_data()
```

As I am new to this myself, I am not aware of how to resolve this issue. I hope that someone can assist me with this problem. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or help in resolving the "tuple index out of range" error. Thank you！！